# PHP Вызов функции (она в файле, в этом файле классов нет) с использованием use function и namespace

Tags: php, функции, импорт, phpunit, namespace

Как правильно вызвать ret_int9_val() ? Не хочу создавать класс обертку для нее.

Расположение файла ModulTest.php
xampp\htdocs\site\tests\ModulTest.php

```
<?php

    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
    use function  App\Modul\ret_int9_val as incr;
       
    
    class ModulTest extends TestCase {
        
        
        protected function setUp() : void {
        
        }
        protected function tearDown() : void {
            
        }
        
        public function testReturnedValue() {
            $a = call_user_func('incr');
            $this->assertEquals( 9, $a );
        }
        
    }

?>
```

Расположение файла Modul.php
xampp\htdocs\site\src\Classes\Modul.php

```
<?php
 
 namespace App;
 
 function ret_int9_val() {
    return 9;
 }

?>
```

Comment: Как вариант подключить через директиву компосера autoload => files нужный файл в котором вы просто будете описывать функции

Comment: Ну или просто заинклюдить в точке входа файл с функциями

Comment: Могу попробовать. Как это сделать?

Comment: Что именно сделать?

Comment: Сейчас постараюсь расписать подробней

Comment: Спасибо, только я не понимаю как это сочетать с phpunit ?

Comment: А в чём разница подключений? Не считая глоба пхпюнита

Comment: Я не понимаю, что неправильно в моем коде. Почему мой код не работает?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант сделать автолоад через компосер, для этого в **composer.json** в директиве **autoload => files** добавляем нужные нам файлы

```
"autoload": {
   ***
   "files": [
      "path/to/functions.php",
  ]
}
```

Ну или в файле входа в приложение тот же индексный **index.php** файл сделать подключение файла с функциями

```
<?php
***
require __DIR__.'/functions.php';
```

И теперь в нужном месте можно вызывать функции из файла functions.php по примеру

```
<?php
class ExampleClass
{
    public $ret_int9_val;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ret_int9_val = ret_int9_val();
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот ответ мне не подходит. В моем коде класс для тестирования, в моем коде используется use function и namespace

Answer (score 0):

Снял видео с ответом.
Только не уверен, что так делать правильно.
Оно то работает, но достаточно ли это элегантно?

(смотрите на двойной скорости 3 мин)

https://youtu.be/X5K0UTL_euM